# Use a Windows WCF Service in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf, service

I am new to the WCF model, but I have created a service, that seems to work in VS2010

Now I would like to access this windows service from an asp.net application.  The reason behind this is:  I want to be able to call the service to connect via SSH to a server, and keep that connection open (as I did in a Windows Forms app)

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?  I tried it with an IIS hosted service, but the connection is lost each time the request finishes.

At least in VS2010 with the tester, I can invoke my connect function, then invoke other functions to query data, then disconnect.

FYI, the local Windows Service and IIS are on the same box.

Comment: IMHO:  Don't use "Windows Service" when talking about a WCF or Web Service.  A Windows Service is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

WCF services by default create a new instance for each request. There are other models, although I'm not sure they will manage as long running a process as you want. This article has some good info on managing sessions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Alternatively, why not use a technology like workflow foundation, that was designed to run / persist / re-awaken long-running processes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx